# Ionic put two background images

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I want to put two images in my ionic app like this. 
[image]
and later this
[image]

i am testing this

```css
  ion-content {
    background: url('../assets/imgs/Untitleddesign.jpg'),
    url('../assets/imgs/Untitleddesign2.jpg') no-repeat !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you want to put a background with a flat color. Use background-color instead.

Comment: I want to get a parallax-like effect with the purple part

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly, but take a look here https://codepen.io/dpu/pen/VwLBZEQ

Comment: yes, Thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

You can load the first image as `background-image` and use `background-color` for the second

```css
    ion-content {
      background-color: #ececec;
      background-image: url('../assets/imgs/Untitleddesign.jpg');
    }
```

But you could get the same effect even without images

```css
    ion-content {
      background-color: #ececec;
      background-image: linear-gradient(152deg, #7e6ecc 40%, #ececec 40% 100%);
    }
```

To make the shape go over the content and partially cover it during the scroll you can use the gradient with transparency in an element positioned absolutely.

```css
ion-content::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    152deg,
    #7e6ecc 20%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 20% 100%
  );
}
```

see: https://codepen.io/dpu/pen/VwLBZEQ